# How to fix a bug in forEach discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I decided to write a code to ban everyone in the array, but when using the command, the bot gives an error

```
message.guild.members.cache.get(element).then(m => m.ban())
                                                 ^

TypeError: message.guild.members.cache.get(...).then is not a function
```

My code:

```
const amo = await db.get(`abig_${message.guild.id}`)
    amo.forEach(element => {
        message.guild.members.cache.get(element).then(m => m.ban())
     })
```

In arrays only id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When fetching the member by using [`cache.get()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection?scrollTo=get), it doesn't return a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) which results in this error. You can just get the value by using it and then you can ban it. Banning a member does return a `Promise` so you need to handle that accordingly. Your corrected code would be like this:

```js
const amo = await db.get(`abig_${message.guild.id}`)
amo.forEach((element) => {
    const user = message.guild.members.cache.get(element)
    if (!user) return message.channel.send('The user does not exist')
    user.ban().then(member => console.log(`Banned ${member.user.tag}!`))
})
```

Comment: Possibly worth mentioning: It's not guaranteed that the user is present in the cache so `user` may be `undefined`.

Comment: Yeah, for that, just an if check to see whether the user exists can be added before banning. Thanks for mentioning it! Edited the answer accordingly

Comment: There's an error -
 Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ban')

Comment: Can you add the complete error in your question?